# GWT for cross device game development

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

How does Google Web Toolkit do in deploying to browsers as well as mobile devices, tablets, televisions, etc.? Would a game targeting specific devices be optimized significantly for the device even when using GWT?

**Edit**

More specifically, I'm asking **how would a game written in GWT perform on a limited system (phone, tablet, tv, etc.)?** Are the general optimizations it does for different browsers good enough for other devices?

Comment: How it does and what optimized significantly mean will vary between everyone you ask. Do you have a more specific question? Sounds like you're interested in starting a discussion about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GWT compiler tries to create browser-specific code, not device specific code. I haven't  worked with it much lately, so I'm not sure what all the browsers it supports these days. Maybe it produces code especially for [desktop] chrome as well as [mobile] chrome. Since mobile is such a big focus these days, I'm sure the GWT compiler is also keeping those mobile browsers in mind.

Comment: **playn** which is a GWT framework, compiles only one version (permutation) that works in most modern browsers. Check the playn.gwt.xml file for details: http://code.google.com/p/playn/source/browse/html/src/playn/PlayN.gwt.xml

Answer (score 3):

GWT is basically a compiler from Java to JavaScript. Instead of compiling Java to JVM Byte Code and running it in JVM, you get JavaScript which you run in (typically) browser. I worked with GWT for couple of years and performance-wise in browser it is ok, but you can write your own Javascript which will be more elegant, readable and little bit faster. The obvious advantage of GWT is that you don't have to write JavaScript, you don't even have to know it. Now your question is reduced to "how does JavaScript perform". And that of course solely depends on the JavaScript interpreter performance on the device in question.

Maybe you have already looked at [playn](http://code.google.com/p/playn/), which is using GWT. Note that graphics are usually done using OpenGL anyway and that means using native code.